# How to implement any-digit in the condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to detect string is list-item-style or not ..., Also I have this code:

```
var test = "1. anything";
if( test[0] == /\d/ && test[1] == '.' ) { alert("it is list-item") }
```

But I never see a `alert()`. Why? I expect to see that alert because first character of that variable is a digit and second character is `.`.

Comment: `test[0] == /\d/` this will not work

Comment: [Regular Expressions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: You can check if test[0]>0 && test[0]<9

Comment: Please notice that your solution assume that the list contains maximum 9 items..

Comment: Use `/^\d+\./.test(str)`. This'll check if the `str` starts with one or more digits followed by a `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using regular expressions correctly. You can't just check if a string equals a regular expression, you need to call a method either on the string or on the regular expression.

```
var test = "1. anything";
if( /\d/.test(test[0]) && test[1] == '.' ) { alert("it is list-item") }
```

Notice that I am using the RegExp [function "test"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Using regular expressions correctly, you can reduce this conditional to:

```
if( /^\d\./.test(test) ) {
   alert("it is list-item");
}
```

Comment: Also to improve your answer, you can add `+` after `\d` in the regex. As @dikesh did ..

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
if (test.match(/^\d+\.*/) !== null) {
    alert('it is list-item');
}
```

Comment: Please add `^` in the beginning of that regex

Comment: This one is a good solution because it supports list items with more than one digit

Comment: `\.*` will match any number of `.` including none. Thus, this will also match `123......`. Also, `match` is used to extract strings, use `RegExp.test()` to check if the string contains some pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this below with working demo !

#### Solution 1: with `test` function

```js
var test = "1. anything";
if( /\d/.test(test[0]) && test[1] == '.' ) { alert("it is list-item") }
```

#### Solution 2 with `Number` Class

```js
    var test = "1. anything";
    if( test[0] == Number(test[0]) && test[1] == '.' ) { alert("it is list-item") }
```